# Why can't I omit the dimensions altogether when initializing a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization

In Visual Studio 2010, this initialization works as expected:

```
char table[2][2] = {
                       {'a', 'b'},
                       {'c', 'd'}
                   };
```

But it does not seem legal to write something like:

```
char table[][] = {
                     {'a', 'b'},
                     {'c', 'd'}
                 };
```

Visual Studio complains that this array may not contain elements of 'that' type, and after compiling, VS reports two errors: a missing index and too many initializations.

**QUESTION**: Why can't I omit the dimensions altogether when initializing a multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only the innermost dimension can be omitted. The size of elements in an array are deduced for the type given to the array variable. The type of elements must therefore have a known size.

- `char a[];` has elements (e.g. `a[0]`) **of size** 1 (8bit), and has an unknown size.
- `char a[6];` has elements **of size** 1, and has size 6.
- `char a[][6];` has elements (e.g. `a[0]`, which is an array) **of size** 6, and has an unknown size.
- `char a[10][6];` has elements **of size** 6. and has size 60.

Not allowed:

- `char a[10][];` would have 10 elements **of unknown size**.
- `char a[][];` would have an unknown number of elements **of unknown size**.

The size of elements is mandatory, the compiler needs it to access elements (through pointer arithmetic).

Comment: In other words, while the size of the array itself may be unknown, the size of the elements cannot be unknown?

Comment: Ah, well, thanks for this bit of information. Upon further thought, it only seems logical, as it always does, does it not? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this an acceptable work-around?

```
char * table [] = { "ab", "cd" };
```

EDIT: Note that it will add an extra '\0' on the end of each string.

Comment: That's a nice solution. But not the answer I was looking for. Still, thanks for showing me a cool trick. :-)