# Why can we omit the first dimension of a multidimensional array when we are passing it to a function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Why can we omit the first dimension of a multidimensional array when we are passing it to a function?

In my programming class, we were told what when passing a multidimensional array to a function we can omit first dimension, for example, `a[10][15][20]` can be passed as `a[][15][20]`.

Why?

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432831/why-cant-i-omit-the-dimensions-altogether-when-initializing-a-multi-dimensional) explains it pretty well.

Comment: Think of an n-dimensional array as a simple array with n-1 dimensional elements. Just as you don't pass the size of a 1 dimensional array, you don't  pass the size of the first dimension of an n dimensional array.

Comment: [Why must I provide a dimension when passing a two-dimensional array to a C function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21691924/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the array will decay to pointer and to calculate offset to the elements of the array you do not need to know the innermost dimension. Offset to `a[i][j][k]` is `i*nj*nk+j*nk+k` (where `nj` and `nk` are corresponding dimensions).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass arrays to functions. Any function declared as taking an array type is automatically adjusted to take the corresponding pointer type. When you use the name of an array in a function call expression it decays to a pointer to its first element.

These four declarations declare the same function:

```
void f(int b[10][15][20]);
void f(int (*b)[15][20]);
void f(int b[][15][20]);
void f(int b[100][15][20]);
```

and, given `int a[10][15][20];`, these function calls are identical:

```
f(a);
f(&a[0]);
```

Comment: uh, the downvote because of the typo? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Presumably the downvote is because my answer is wrong or unhelpful.

Comment: I'd expect downvote on totally offtopic, misleading or harmful answers, so I've been wondering what I'm missing here…

Comment: No, I didn't downvote it for the typo, I don't know who downvoted.

Comment: @CBBailey  `void f(int b[100][15][20]);` it should be `10` rather than `100` so it's same as first way. So there should not be 4th way.