# how declaring an array as argument doesn't need a bound for the 1st dimension?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

In C it's not possible to declare a 2D array as an argument without bounding the second dimension, while it's possible for the first dimension to have no bounds.
I was wondering how does the compiler keeps track of the first dimension's length and why it doesn't do the same for further dimensions?

As compiling the following code wouldn't work:

```
int func(int array[][]) {
  return 0;
}
```

and would yield

```
error: declaration of ‘array’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
```

Comment: You should post an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must I provide a dimension when passing a two-dimensional array to a C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691924/why-must-i-provide-a-dimension-when-passing-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-c-funct)

Comment: The compiler does not keep track of the first dimension, because it dos not need it to access a cell in the array. It only needs the second dimension, since the address of a (row,col) cell is : address of the array + row * nb columns + col. Where nb columns is you guessed the second dimension.

Comment: It's the same reason you don't have to specify the length of a 1-dimensional array argument.

Comment: @JoëlHecht How does the compiler know where the array ends then? if it doesn't then what happens when you try to read an out of range row?

Comment: (1) It doesn't know. (2) Chaos happens, so don't do that. It's your responsibility to ensure that.

Comment: @parham even if you provide a function with a length say `void func(char arr[100])` the `100` is ignored.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The `100` is evaluated and then discarded. For example, with Apple LLVM 10.0.1 and clang-1001.0.46.4, `#include <stdio.h>` / `void foo(char arr[printf("Hello, world.\n")]) {}` / `int main(void) { foo(0); }` prints “Hello, world.” Some compilers might not do this; the C standard is not clear, but I think Clang and GCC both do.

Comment: In C, arrays don't check if indices are in bounds for you. If you access an out-of-bounds index, you get [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) which means the C standard doesn't restrict the behavior of your program at all, so anything can happen. Because the C standard and potentially your compiler doesn't care what UB does, weird things can happen. For example, reading past the end of an array may result in a garbage value or a segmentation fault among many other things especially if the compiler optimizes based on the assumption that UB never happens.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's interesting, MSVC doesn't support variable length arrays and generates two errors for your function definition: *expected constant expression*, and *cannot allocate an array of constant size 0*. Defining as `void foo(char arr[0])` gives the second error. It's only happy with a non-0 length or `[]` none. I had thought that a VLA's length must be passed as another function argument, such as `void foo(int x, int a[][x]);` although maybe that's not the case for a 1-dimensional array, whose length isn't actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the compiler does not keep track of the first dimension of an array argument/parameter. (If it does, this is an extension to what the C standard requires, possibly as part of a feature to provide bounds checking.) It is actually impossible to pass an array as an argument in C, and it is impossible for a routine to declare an array as a parameter.

When a function parameter is declared as an array, it is automatically adjusted to be a pointer, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 7:

> A declaration of a parameter as “array of *type*” shall be adjusted to “qualified pointer to *type*”, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation…

When an array is given as a function argument, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 3:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial element of the array object…

Thus an array is never passed as an argument nor received as a parameter. Only pointers are passed.

The C implementation never needs the length of the array to provide any standard C behavior. Suppose, for example, a parameter is declared as `int x[3][4]`. This is automatically adjusted to be `int (*x)[4]`. Then, if the code in the function uses `x[i][j]`, the C implementation needs to find that element in memory. It is `i*4+j` elements beyond where `x` points. The implementation needs the second dimension to do the calculation, because it has to increment by `i` subarrays to find element `x[i][j]`. Since it is increment by subarrays, it needs to know how big the subarrays are.

However, the C implementation does not need to know how big the array is. No expression will require it to use the size of the array. So having just the pointer to the first element of the array is enough.